# Google Drive notifications on edits

Tags: google-drive, notifications

Is it possible to configure Google Drive to notify me by email to my Gmail account when someone else edits a shared document of which I'm owner?

Note: I think I can be notified when someone else adds a comment, but not for simple edits...

Comment: It doesn't look like it, but are you aware of the new [activity stream for Google Drive](http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2014/01/a-new-activity-stream-in-drive-shows.html)? All you need to do is visit drive.google.com and see all the actions taken on your files.

Comment: Thanks @AlE., I'm aware of that new feature, which I think is cool, but I'd like to be able to avoid visiting Drive itself to get the updates...

Answer (score 1):

It is  possible with Google Drive API. You can set up a push notification for this type of event.

I found [this course Level 9](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-drive). Teaches you how to set up push notifications when changes happen to a file.

Answer (score 1):

For google spreadsheets there is the option to enable it in the sheet itself:

[image: Notification Rules]

[image: Define type of notification]

I'm not aware of any way to do this with other documents except the activity stream or using scripts. bbatman describes in his answer how to do this.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info - I wonder why they do not apply that to all types of files!

Comment: Me too :). Seems to me sometimes as if it is developed in different groups which don't exchange their ideas good enough.

Comment: Is there still no way to enable this for drive documents that are not spreadsheets? (First I thought the recent UI upgrade has done away with this feature, but it's still there - alas, only for spreadsheets. Awful.)

Comment: Not aware of any changes. Waiting for the feature also.